# Python Goose-extractor creats a folder in tmp called goose and is filling it with files

Tags: python, goose

I'm using goose-extractor to parse a list of urls from a dictionary key.
I'm using python 2.7.6 
My code is given below :

```
import json
import re
import sys
from goose import Goose
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongoobj = MongoClient()
coll = mongoobj.db_name.coll_name
gobj = Goose()
eachkey = sys.argv[1]
print "\n "+eachkey
all_data = []
total_data = len(json_data[eachkey])
count = 0.0
for each_link in json_data[eachkey]:
    print "\r",str(round(count/total_data,2)),
    count += 1
    try:
        data = gobj.extract(each_link)
        new_data =" ".join( re.findall(r"\b\w+\b",data.cleaned_text))
        text = ""
        if new_data:
             text = new_data
        elif data.meta_description:
             text = " ".join(re.findall(r"\b\w+\b", data.title + " " + data.meta_description))
        if text:
            coll.insert_one({"text":text, "label":eachkey, "title":data.title})
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Goose seems to be creating a folder in tmp called goose/
it is filling it with tmp files and it has filled up my system space.. I don't want this to crash my system. Is there something I'm doing wrong that garbage collection is not happening correctly.

Comment: Looking at Goose source, it should call `Crawler.relase_resources()` after each `Crawler.crawl()` (called by `Goose.extract()`->`Goose.crawl()`) completes. I'd investigate if and why it doesn't clear already crawled sites. On the other hand, maybe you're expecting a bit too much from a module written by people who cannot bother to spellcheck their function names...

Comment: I found a blog which put goose in the top 5 article scraping python tools.. I just thought if it hit the top 5 then it must probably be good., However thank you for your help. I have for the time being modified utils/__init__.py to remove the time.time() from being a part of the file names.. so that if it creates a file then for the same url name there is only 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

Goose stores the data temporary on the local storage before it can extract the content from it , 
i am not aware of any crawler which can do this on the go efficiently without using some amount of local storage ,

the local storage path can be configured from the file `configuration.py as  self.local_storage_path =` .
also in that file set `self.debug =False` to avoid further load .

also after the goose is done use `release_resources()` function as suggested in the comments , 
it looks like this

```
def relase_resources(self):
        path = os.path.join(self.config.local_storage_path, '%s_*' % self.article.link_hash)
        for fname in glob.glob(path):
            try:
                os.remove(fname)
            except OSError:
                # TODO better log handling
                pass
```

and clears the temp resources.

generally tmp files of even a few hundred mid level sources should not be enough to crash the system .